# Keep dynamically created check boxes checked after page is refreshed

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have multiple check boxes with unique id, these are created dynamically and I need the check box clicked to be checked when the page is refreshed. I used the code below, but this checks all the check boxes upon refresh.

```
$(function(){
    var test = localStorage.input === 'true'? true: false;
    $('input').prop('checked', test || false);
});

$('input').on('change', function() {
    localStorage.input = $(this).is(':checked');
    console.log($(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Its probably better to be using cookies to store the input information along it's not sensitive. localStorage is a bit overkill for simple storage, since it won't be removed until you or the users removes it.

Comment: @Jamie Sterling, I am open to that, but I am new to Javascript, and I dont know how to do that

Comment: I'll write an answer for you on how to create and manage inputs using javascript cookies. We've all been there. :-)

Comment: On the other hand, cookies get send up (and back) with every HTTP request to that server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    if (sessionStorage.getItem('checked-checkboxes') && $.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem('checked-checkboxes')).length !== 0)
    {
        var arrCheckedCheckboxes = $.parseJSON(sessionStorage.getItem('checked-checkboxes'));
        //Convert checked checkboxes array to comma seprated id
        $(arrCheckedCheckboxes.toString()).prop('checked', true);
    }
    $("input:checkbox").change(function () {
        var arrCheckedCheckboxes = [];
        // Get all checked checkboxes
        $.each($("input:checkbox:checked"), function () {
            arrCheckedCheckboxes.push("#" + $(this).attr('id'));
        });
        // Convert checked checkboxes array to JSON ans store it in session storage
        sessionStorage.setItem('checked-checkboxes', JSON.stringify(arrCheckedCheckboxes));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Checkbox 1: <input type="checkbox" id="chk1"> <br>
Checkbox 2: <input type="checkbox" id="chk2"> <br>
Checkbox 3: <input type="checkbox" id="chk3"> <br>
Checkbox 4: <input type="checkbox" id="chk4"> <br>
Checkbox 5: <input type="checkbox" id="chk5"> <br>
```

Comment: Kindly check my updated answer. It's shorter than previous answer.